# ADD r0, r1, #0 vs MOV r0, r1?

Tags: assembly, arm

I would think that they both achieve the same effect but **mov** would be easier to read and, thus, used more often (not that machines care about that, right?) However, when looking at some disassembled code, I've often noticed `add r-something, r-something, #0` being used instead.

Is there a reason for this or is it just the compiler making life hard for those who would wish to read the assembled code?

**Edit:**

I was disassembling ARM Thumb. Specifically, it was `movs r7, r1` and adds `r7, r1, #0`. With the condition flags not being used afterwards. And the hex for those two were `000f` and `1c0f` respectively. I guess I should have specified which instruction set I was talking about =x

Comment: Don't those two instructions in fact assemble to the exact same opcode on most RISC platforms? The disassembler just picked the most literal translation

Comment: I think, this is the disassebmler which can't invert all macro expansions... You can think about mov as macro, because some CPUs which have `ADD rA, rB, #0` usually have no `MOV rA, rB` hardwire instruction.

Comment: Ahh.. Thanks for the answers! But, I was disassembling ARM Thumb. Specifically, it was `movs r7, r1` and `adds r7, r1, #0`. With the condition flags not being used afterwards. And the hex for those two were `000f` and `1c0f` respectively. I guess I should have specified which instruction set I was talking about =x It's like the instructions used to achieve the same thing seem rather.. Inconsistent.

Comment: What optimization level do you use?  If you are using `-O0`, then it is quite common for the compiler to do odd things.  Assembler readability of compiler output is almost never a design goal.  If the instruction executes in the same or less time, the compiler will use it.  It does not care what it looks like to a human.  For instance, in order to compile faster, an `add rx, ry, #N` maybe done in a sequence that sometimes adds non-zero.  Most programmers what faster compiles.  To special case the compiler logic will  slow compiles down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another point to consider with compiled code is instruction scheduling - the compiler may choose different instructions to do the 'same' thing depending on the surrounding code for performance reasons. Say you have something like:

```
MOV r0, r1
MOV r2, r3
```

A simple CPU with a fairly restricted pipeline might only be able to execute one `MOV` at a time, but could be capable of dual-issuing certain arithmetic instructions, thus by doing this:

```
MOV r0, r1
ADD r2, r3, #0
```

both instructions may execute in the same cycle and the code is twice as fast.

On ARM<sup>1</sup> `MOV rd,rm` is actually `LSL rd, rm, #0`, so as a generic optimisation interleaving `MOV` and `ADD` this way is likely a net gain on anything that can pipeline the shifter and adder in parallel, without any disadvantage to a strictly scalar in-order core that can't.

---

[1]Conceptually at least, and for the 'basic' encodings in both ARM and Thumb - for simplicity I'm eliding flag-setting and the other Thumb encodings that exist for IT block and high regs vs. low regs complications.

Answer (score 3):

Would depend (in part) on what processor you're talking about.  For example, on some, there isn't really a MOV instruction in the processor; the assembler translates it into the add-0 you describe, so that when you disassembled you couldn't tell how that instruction was specified in the original assembly code.

Comment: Indeed. The main reason for the MIPS to not require a *standalone* `MOV` instruction is because it has a register (r0 or $0) which is always zero (you cannot change that register's value!) Thus the `MOV` is equivalent to `ADD rn, rm, $0`. From what I recall, the SGI MIPS compiler would use `OR rn, rm, $0` instead. But that's very much the same thing, except that the OR may use the same unit as addressing mode so the ADD may be better in many circumstances on newer processors. Note that they could as well have used a SUB or an XOR.